# How do you open a FileOutpuStream to a File created by registerForActivityResult with Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT

Tags: file, kotlin, android-intent, outputstream, fileoutputstream

I'm using Kotlin to create a Program, that takes the Data inside a Database and exports it to a File, using gson.
The File is created using the File-Chooser-Activity and i plan to use mainly use the Download-Folder, although the User should be able to choose any folder regardless
I plan to use a forEach-Loop to write the Data into the File. Sadly, I struggle with creating a FileOutputStream from the returning Intent.  So how do I go from

```
val resultData: Intent? = result.data
```

to

```
val outputstream = FileOutputStream(filename,true)
```

or

```
val outputstream = FileOutputStream(file:File,true)
```

Also, I would appreaceate it, if somebody could explain to me the difference between OutputStream and FileOutputStream.
From what I've gathered, Outputstream is just an Abstract, typeless version of FileOutputStream.